# How to get TopVerticalLayout constraint right in iOS7?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm having the following Storyboard view-controller setup:
Navigation-TableView-TabBar-{TabItem1View,TabItem2View}
[image]

If I run in an iOS8.1 simulator the TabItem1View shows correct behaviour regarding the top layer-out buttons like:
[image]

When I rotate and switch to TabItem2View and back to TabItem1View everything still seems OK, just as designed in Storyboard with AutoLayout.

[image]
[image]

However when I run in an iOS7 simulator the TabItem1View top-buttons don't align up to the TopLayoutGuide and only when I select TabItem2 (which show up correctly) and back to TabItem1 they seem to be correct (as designed in Storyboard). This behaviour also occurs when I rotate either TabItem1View or TabItem2View and switch between the two of them.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I read that disabling the ExtendEdges Under Top/Bottom bar seems one of the tricks you can apply, but I haven't found any other tricks which prevents the TabItem1View top buttons dancing up and down when switching TabItems or device rotation.

This problem is causing a lot of frustration regarding Autolayout and I don't see any means yet to solve this. Is it one of the many bugs regarding Autolayout iOS7/iOS8/Xcode? I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 and started this project with a fresh new Autolayout and only disabling the "Use size classes" feature. Since I'm almost pulling out all my remaining hear out of frustration, I don't want to end up bold at this age, so if anybody knows a fix, I'll be very happy to try it. Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: After some debugging I noticed that the self.topLayoutGuide.frame.height attribute changes from 0 to 20 when I either rotate in iOS7 or switch between TabBarItems. Since the self.topLayoutGuide is a readonly attribute I need to figure out how to change this in code in the appropriate viewDidAppear and didRotatieFromInterfaceOrientation. Anybody a tip how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you set the top to top of your superview instead of topLayoutGuide